How To Generate And Execute A Dynamic, Parameterized Query In Postgresql
As the question title suggests, I am trying to build a dynamic, parameterized query to update a contact record in my database. The params being passed in are aid (integer) cid (integer) oid(varchar) and updateobject (json). The json object being sent in is dynamic itself (meaning it doesn't always include the same keys, and not all keys will have non-null values) however every key it DOES include is guaranteed to exist in the database as a column name. This is the code I have so far:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatecontact(
    aid INT,
    cid INT,
    oid TEXT,
    updaterecord JSON
) RETURNS JSON AS $$
DECLARE
    sql_query TEXT := 'UPDATE contacts SET ';
    param_values TEXT[] := ARRAY[]::TEXT[];
    param_count INTEGER := 0;
    text_fields TEXT[] := ARRAY['firstname','lastname','gender'];
    boolean_fields TEXT[] := ARRAY['consent'];
    array_fields TEXT[] := ARRAY['anis', 'emails'];
    jsonb_fields TEXT[] := ARRAY['providers'];
    numeric_fields TEXT[] := ARRAY['addresslat', 'addresslong'];
    key TEXT;
    value JSON;
    updated_rows INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR key, value IN SELECT * FROM json_each(updaterecord) LOOP
        IF key != 'id' THEN
            param_count := param_count + 1;
            CASE
                WHEN key = ANY(text_fields) THEN
                    sql_query := sql_query || format('%I = CASE WHEN $%s::text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE $%s::text END, ', key, param_count, param_count);
                WHEN key = ANY(boolean_fields) THEN
                    sql_query := sql_query || format('%I = CASE WHEN $%s::text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE $%s::boolean END, ', key, param_count, param_count);
                WHEN key = ANY(array_fields) THEN
                    sql_query := sql_query || format('%I = CASE WHEN $%s::text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE $%s::text[] END, ', key, param_count, param_count);
                WHEN key = ANY(jsonb_fields) THEN
                    sql_query := sql_query || format('%I = CASE WHEN $%s::text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE $%s::jsonb END, ', key, param_count, param_count);
                WHEN key = ANY(numeric_fields) THEN
                    sql_query := sql_query || format('%I = CASE WHEN $%s::text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE $%s::numeric END, ', key, param_count, param_count);
            END CASE;
            param_values := array_append(param_values, updaterecord->>key);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF param_count > 0 THEN
        sql_query := left(sql_query, -2);
    END IF;
    param_count := param_count + 1;
    sql_query := sql_query || format(' WHERE agentid = $%s', param_count);
    param_values := array_append(param_values, aid::TEXT);
    param_count := param_count + 1;
    sql_query := sql_query || format(' AND id = $%s', param_count);
    param_values := array_append(param_values, cid::TEXT);
    param_count := param_count + 1;
    sql_query := sql_query || format(' AND orgid = $%s', param_count);
    param_values := array_append(param_values, oid);
    RAISE NOTICE 'Generated SQL Query: %', sql_query;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Parameter Array: %', param_values;
    EXECUTE sql_query USING param_values;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS updated_rows = ROW_COUNT;
    RETURN json_build_object('statusCode', CASE WHEN updated_rows > 0 THEN '200' ELSE '201' END);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

This is how I am attempting to call the function, and the error that it is spitting out. I'm positive this is close though:
SELECT updatecontact(
    123,  -- aid
    4554,  -- cid
    '423-423-422',  -- oid
    '{"lastname": "Smith", "firstname":"Mike"}'::JSON 
);


NOTICE:  Generated SQL Query: UPDATE contacts SET lastname = CASE WHEN $1::text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE $1::text END, firstname = CASE WHEN $2::text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE $2::text END WHERE agentid = $3 AND id = $4 AND orgid = $5
NOTICE:  Parameter Array: {Smith,Mike,123,4554,423-423-422}

ERROR:  there is no parameter $3
LINE 1: ... NULL THEN NULL ELSE $2::text END WHERE agentid = $3 AND id ...
^
QUERY:  UPDATE contacts SET lastname = CASE WHEN $1::text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE $1::text END, firstname = CASE WHEN $2::text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE $2::text END WHERE agentid = $3 AND id = $4 AND orgid = $5
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function updatecontact(integer,integer,text,json) line 51 at EXECUTE
The above function also behaves the same way if a null value is passed for any of the key values. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Each $ parameter is associated with the corresponding expression from the USING clause. EXECUTE ... USING param_values only has a single expression in the USING clause. To use a single array to pass multiple parameter values, replace the $# parameters in the query with $1[#]; e.g., change $2 to $1[2].

@JohnH thank you, the idea to parameterize the query to begin with was to (unsurprisingly) try and limit exposure to SQL injections... hypothetically, should using this single array/param with sub params do the job there?

The protection from SQL injection attacks is a result of using bound variables to pass parameters. Since param_values is a bound variable, the query is still protected. For queries that have a fixed number of parameters, it's more readable to pass them as a list in the USING clause; however, when there are a variable number of parameters, passing them as elements of an array works well.
